# mysqli.reconnect will it re-run the query which failed due to a timeout?

Tags: mysql, timeout, reconnect

Recently I have noticed that mysql connections are timing out, increasing wait_timeout has helped this. However it still happens.

We have also enabled mysqli.reconnect in an attempt to catch the issue and allow the script to continue running. However I can't see anywhere if the SQL which was run and failed due to a timeout, would automatically get re-run on the reconnection, as I would hope. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Reading the documentation, it seems that you need to use `mysqli::ping()` to automatically reconnect. If you run `ping()` before any query, the reconnect will happen at that time.